# How to resolve SQL database data motion errors in Azure CD

Tags: sql-server, azure, continuous-deployment

We are using azure CI CD for deploying Azure SQL database changes. It worked fine when it was just normal SP, view, function changes but it failed when we tried to deploy tables with constraints, security policies etc. Not sure how to use pre-post script because we dont want it to execute multiple times.

Edit: We are expecting solution on pre and post script deployment technique which will automatically check all the validations and rebuild constrains and security policies.

This error we are getting in CD pipeline:

> 2020-11-12T07:29:40.7874247Z
> ##[error] Verification of the deployment plan failed.
> 2020-11-12T07:29:40.8077122Z
> ##[error]Error SQL71616: SR0111 : Microsoft.Rules.Data.DeploymentValidation : The current operation will cause data motion on table [dbo].[campaignLoop]. Data motion can not be performed on this table because it has
> 2020-11-12T07:29:40.8241423Z
> ##[error]row level security enabled by policy [dbo].[campaignLoop_SpidFilter_Policy]. To allow this operation use SqlPackage.exe with option /p:AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement=true

Comment: I guess the error message tells about the issue. So, you have to disable row level security or deploy the dacpac with an option `/p:AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement=true`

Comment: @AlexanderVolok We tried adding this option but we don't want to skip any security policy or constraint validations. We are expecting solution on pre and post script deployment technique which will automatically check all the validations and rebuild constrains and security policies.